# Can you execute another EXE file from within a C# console application?

Tags: c#, console-application

Can you execute another EXE file from within a C# console application?

- Can you pass arguments?
- Can you get the exit code back?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Like this:

```
        var proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "something.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-v -s -a";
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        var exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
        proc.Close();
```