# Frontend creation using C++

Tags: c++

I have data generation code written in C++. Is it possible to create a frontend using C# and pass values to the data generation code written in C++?

I'm using [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010).

Comment: Yes. It is possible. But to give you any more help, we'll need more information.

Comment: This is too vague. A front-end to what ? what is the intended workflow ?

Comment: the frontend is intended to start and stop the data generation.few values required for data generation are to be manually given using the frontend

Answer (score 1):

You could pick any of interop options that .NET ecosystem provides:

- Use [Platform invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx)
- wrap your C++ logic into COM interface and use it from .NET app via [runtime callable wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx), i.e. [COM interop](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9776/COM-Interoperability-in-NET-Framework-Part-I)
- make your C++ library and [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI) dll and use it directly from .NET

Of course, you always have 'classic' interop options, like having TCP/IP client-server, but this is overkill if you just need to call into methods of another dll.

Answer (score 0):

Any C# program can easily access the functions of a DLL (that can be written in C++) thanks to the [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) mechanism.

As an alternative, you can also call executable files from C#, as in Stack Overflow question *[Can you execute another EXE file from within a C# console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832962/can-you-execute-another-exe-from-within-a-c-sharp-console-application/1833006#1833006)*.

You could also have a look at [SWIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG).