# Sending multiple arguments to cmd C#

Tags: c#, process, cmd, args

I currently have a piece of code that opens a cmd prompt using admin rights. What I can't seem to manage is to send a couple of commands to be carried out. I currently have the following code:

```
 var proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
 proc.UseShellExecute = true;
 proc.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";
 proc.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
 proc.Verb = "runas";

 try
 {
      Process.Start(proc);
      Console.WriteLine("Successfully elevated!");
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
      Console.WriteLine("Failed to elevate.");
 }
```

How would I go about adding a few commands for example what if I wanted to change dir then run an exe file? I am sure it is something very simple I have missed. I have tried giving arguements like so:

```
  proc.Arguments = "cd \\temp";
```

Comment: If you haven't read it over already, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx may have some info for you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending commands to cmd prompt in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767654/sending-commands-to-cmd-prompt-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can call a .exe from a given filepath using a process.

Like the answer in this: [Can you execute another EXE file from within a C# console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832962/can-you-execute-another-exe-file-from-within-a-c-sharp-console-application)

EDIT:
If you want the directory the program is running from with temp at the end you can do:

```
string filepath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\temp\programToRun.exe";
```

Comment: `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` does not return the directory that the program is running in. Its only true if there has never been a call to `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()`. `GetCurrentDirectory` gets the current *working* directory, not the application directory.

Comment: I literally need to just run these 2 commands:

cd \cports-x64

then

cports.exe /close * * * 1869