# How can I read console input before open a window in a C# Form Application?

Tags: c#, forms, input, console, readline

I am making a program that ask you if you want to run your application on console or in GUI. I tried to make a read from the console before open the GUI but it doesn't work. The if don't evaluates the input. I'm new with C#.

[This is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8GGH.png)

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST ATTEMPT :** I'd say - try to build two seperate projects( one for console and one for windows form). Build those two projects. You'll get separate executable files.
Then in the console invoke the form's executable file when necessary.

> I think this link might help you -
>   [Can you execute another EXE file from within a C# console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832962/can-you-execute-another-exe-file-from-within-a-c-sharp-console-application)
>
> **Edited** :
>    I think you've two main methods in the same namespace. So, your project has two entry points. Two entry points will ultimately confuse you machine :) . So, you need to create two separate projects( i.e two separate namespaces will be created). Also take a look at this code by one of my favourite youtubers Jerry_aka_Barnacules https://github.com/Barnacules/Codegasm/blob/master/Test%20App%203%20-%20Jarvis/Program.cs .

Also take a look at his video at youtube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1In6NbJt5E&list=PLEbaEyM-xt9mVQEAXGlRRmbO2Qp_oqF-n&index=3

Also try creating a solution with two projects.

By the way you can learn a lot by visiting these links. I'm suggesting you that because you said you're new to C#.

I hope you can solve your problem easily by referring to those links. So, best of luck for that.

I'm new to stackOverflow and I'm learning new stuffs. So, please let me know whether my suggestion helped you or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a solution with 2 project, one console application and the other windows form application, and in the first one you can call the other application adding some references.